# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, real-time

I am trying to implement a real time group video chat; when the first browser opens the page everything is ok but when I want to open that page as a second user it will come up with this error.
I am trying to implement a real time group video chat; when the first browser opens the page everything is ok but when I want to open that page as a second user it will come up with this error.

And it does not broadcast the shared screen

Can anyone help me to fix this

This the code that I'm using:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

function App() {
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [peers, setPeers] = useState([]);
  const userVideoRef = useRef();
  const peersRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        userVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;

        socket.emit('join-room', roomId, userId);

        socket.on('user-connected', (newUserId) => {
          connectToNewUser(newUserId, stream);
        });

        socket.on('user-disconnected', (disconnectedUserId) => {
          const peer = peersRef.current.find((p) => p.userId === disconnectedUserId);
          if (peer) {
            peer.peer.destroy();
          }
          setPeers((prevPeers) => prevPeers.filter((p) => p.userId !== disconnectedUserId));
        });

        socket.on('receive-message', ({ userId, message }) => {
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, `${userId}: ${message}`]);
        });

        socket.on('user-share-screen', ({ userId, screenStream }) => {
          connectToNewUser(userId, screenStream, true);
        });
      });

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const connectToNewUser = (newUserId, userStream, isScreen = false) => {
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: true,
      trickle: false,
      stream: userStream,
    });
  
    peer.on('signal', (offer) => {
      socket.emit('offer', roomId, newUserId, offer);
    });
  
    peer.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('Data received:', data);
    });
  
    peer.on('stream', (userVideoStream) => {
      setPeers((prevPeers) => [...prevPeers, { userId: newUserId, stream: userVideoStream, isScreen }]);
    });
  
    socket.on('receive-answer', (answerUserId, answer) => {
      if (answerUserId === newUserId) {
        peer.signal(answer);
      }
    });
  
    socket.on('receive-ice-candidate', (iceCandidateUserId, iceCandidate) => {
      if (iceCandidateUserId === newUserId) {
        peer.signal(iceCandidate);
      }
    });
  
    peersRef.current.push({ userId: newUserId, peer });
  };
  

  const sendMessage = (message) => {
    socket.emit('send-message', message);
    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, `You: ${message}`]);
  };

  const shareScreen = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('screen is groing sharing');
      const screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
      console.log('Screen stream:', screenStream);
  
      // Stop the existing user media stream
      const userMediaStream = userVideoRef.current.srcObject;
      if (userMediaStream) {
        const tracks = userMediaStream.getTracks();
        tracks.forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }
  
      userVideoRef.current.srcObject = screenStream;
  
      peersRef.current.forEach((peer) => {
        if (peer.peer._isInitiator) {
          const sender = peer.peer._pc.getSenders().find((s) => s.track.kind === 'video');
          if (sender) {
            sender.replaceTrack(screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
          } else {
            console.error('No video sender found.');
          }
        }
      });
  
      socket.emit('share-screen', screenStream);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sharing screen:', error.message);
    }
  };
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Room ID:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={roomId}
          onChange={(e) => setRoomId(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter Room ID"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>User ID:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={userId}
          onChange={(e) => setUserId(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter User ID"
        />
      </div>
      <video ref={userVideoRef} autoPlay muted style={{ width: '200px' }} />
      <div>
        <h3>Peers:</h3>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          {peers.map((peer) => (
            <video key={peer.userId} autoPlay playsInline style={{ width: '200px', margin: '5px' }} ref={(el) => el && (el.srcObject = peer.stream)} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={shareScreen}>Share Screen</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Chat:</h3>
        <ul>
          {messages.map((message, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{message}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type your message..."
          onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && sendMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows most of webcam drivers are blocking, it means that it's not possible to access one webcam more then once at the same time. You can consider using virtual webcam as a second one or connect second physical webcam.